# .shp incompatibilty issue between ArcGIS and QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, google-earth

I received a .shp file from an ArcGIS user. He said it was in SAD69UTM23S, and indeed it is (checked it in QGIS properties tab). However QGIS is not placing it correctly (using QuickMapServices as reference and other correctly placed .shp files I have; yes OTF reprojection is enabled). I even checked coordinates (of individual points) taken from the attributes table manually converting them and putting in Google Earth, they were equally misplaced.

However, when loaded the original .shp file in Google Earth all the points were in the right places. So I figured it was actually WGS84UTM rather than SAD69 as they said. I changed it in QGIS but it was also misplaced, this time though by a smaller distance.

Is there some kind of compatibility between ArcGIS and Google Earth that doesn't exist between ArcGIS and QGIS?

I don't get it why would Google Earth place the layer correctly but QGIS won't. In fact, apparently Google Earth is using different coordinates for the points (different from those in the attributes table).

Figures below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: No need to apologize about the length but please use line breaks to keep it readable.

Comment: Can you explain how have "changed" the coordinates in QGIS?

Comment: right click > properties > general > resetting layer CRS in the Coordinate reference system tab

Comment: If you wan to reproject a layer you have to right click and choose save as. In the dialog box, among other things you have to declare which CRS you want. The process you mention does not reproject a file

Comment: I know it doesn't but that wasn't the point in the first place. I just wanted to redefine the CRS of the layer I received, which could be wrong. After all Google Earth was able to place points correctly with the same file.

Comment: problem persists here and I really need help. I installed ArcGIS just to check, and the same file goes fine there. Tried exporting it again and still QGIS will misplace it.